# Difference of defining a variable inside and outside a function

Tags: javascript

New to javascript here.

The Team Treehouse blog has a small tutorial on how to build a timer in javascript. It is basically the following code:

```
<h1 id="timer">Loading</h1>

var updateMessage = function(){ 
  var date = Date();
  var message = document.getElementById("timer");
  message.innerHTML = "The time is " + date;
}

var timer = setInterval(updateMessage, 500);
```

This works fine and all. However I want to use `date` for multiple functions. I tried the following..

```
var date = Date();
var updateMessage = function(){ 
  var message = document.getElementById("timer");
  message.innerHTML = "The time is " + date;
}
```

..but now it doesn't work realtime. Whenever I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> it gives back the correct time but it's not updated realtime anymore.

Why is this? I thought that when I declare a variable outside of a function, it would become a global function which could be used anywhere.

Comment: I'm talking about the same example. I just moved `var date = Date();` to outside the function and it stopped working.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I explained it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = Date();
var updateMessage = function(){ 
  var message = document.getElementById("timer");
  message.innerHTML = "The time is " + date;
}
```

in above case `var date` is a **variable whose value is assigned when script loaded**.

and in another case `var date` is assign all time **when the updateMessage is called**

```
var updateMessage = function(){ 
  var date = Date();
  var message = document.getElementById("timer");
  message.innerHTML = "The time is " + date;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `Date()` is the time you call it, it does not keep updating!

If you want to share it, update it inside of the function.

```
var date;
var updateMessage = function(){ 
   date = new Date();
  var message = document.getElementById("timer");
  message.innerHTML = "The time is " + date;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for shedding some light!

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = Date();
```

Is only executed once when script loads. The variable date stays the same throughout the lifetime of the webpage. That is why it only changes when you refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not where you define the `date` variable but where and how many times you are calling the `Date()` function.

Declaring it globally but making the necessary call everytime you need is also a valid solution.

```
var date; // declaration

var updateMessage = function(){ 
  var message = document.getElementById("timer");
  date = Date(); // call to Date() everytime updateMessage is executed
  message.innerHTML = "The time is " + date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are missing setInterval in second example?

Apart from that, you were on the right track, but with a little problem: The way you are doing it now, you are getting the Date() when you load the page, and just use the same date over and over.

Something like this should work for you, as it would give you a global variable while changing the date dinamically:

```
var date = Date();
var updateMessage = function(){ 
  date = Date();
  var message = document.getElementById("timer");
  message.innerHTML = "The time is " + date;
}
```